# How Does Electricity Work Voltage/Amperage?

Tags: voltage, plug

Probably some basic questions however I can't seem to find an answer to a few based on the way I phrase it online unfortunately. I never really delved into the whole electrics field/terms much until now.

Using a 4-plug household extension lead connected to a single 240 V house socket as an example rated:

Power Voltage Supply: 240 V 
Amp Rating: 13 A 
Power Output (Watts/Kw): 3120 W

**Q1.** Power output is always determined by voltage x amp? In this case 240 V x 13 A = 3120 W?

**Q2.** I understand that a maximum of 4 appliances connected to the lead SHOULD NOT exceed a combined amp draw/power output of 13 A/3120 W, therefore lets say 4 chargers rated 3 A/720W would be just below the threshold?

**Q3.** Trying to understand what impact/why voltage doesn't work similar to amps in the sense that those 4 devices rated at 240 V would be 240 V x 4 (same time), but that has no impact on functionality if that makes sense?

Comment: See also: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/586368/2028, https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/234235/2028, and https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings

Answer (score 0):

If you review some of the posts I linked in comments, it should clear up many of your questions.

1. Power is energy being consumed, or a rate of work being done.

   - A power rating on a power *supply* is its potential to do work. *"How much power can this supply provide?"*
   - A rating on an extension outlet or splitter is meant to be a convenient way to know the maximum combined power of attached loads the extension is designed to safely handle. Although current is what really matters, it's often shown as power because appliances do the same. *"How much current can I safely draw through this splitter?"*
   - A power specification on an appliance represents its maximum power consumption. *"How much power will this device require?"*
2. Technically the number of plugs doesn't matter. You could have a 4-outlet extension, or a 40-outlet extension. What matters is total current. The idea is to draw less current than the weakest link in the delivery chain. If a mains outlet can deliver 15 A but an outlet extension (aka splitter, outlet strip, power strip, etc.) is only rated for 13 A, then you should not exceed 13 A downstream from the extension or 15 A downstream from the mains outlet. You are correct in your example that four 3 A or 720 W loads are just under the limit (\$4 \times 3 A = 12 A\$ or \$4 \times 720 W = 2880 W\$). But just to be clear, if those loads were 4 A or 960 W each, you could only connect three of them before exceeding the limit.
3. Devices in the above scenario are connected in parallel, which means they share the same voltage (240 V). Writing "240 V x 4" reveals your misunderstanding because this equation means that the voltage would be additive, but it isn't.

In this example, I've drawn a voltage source (V1) which represents your mains outlet. Then an ammeter (current meter, AM_Sum) which measures the current in this hypothetical system. Each load (R1 through R4) also has its own ammeter (AM1 through AM4). Note that all loads are connected to the same pair of wires, which means they are all connected to the same voltage, or potential. Note how they are all **parallel** to each other in this diagram.

If you turn on (or plug in) R1, current flows through it and whatever R1 is could be said to be doing work or consuming power. AM1 and AM_Sum would show effectively the same amount of current being drawn.

If you then turn on R2, current flows through it as well. The current AM1 and AM2 are additive (not the voltage), and this would be shown on AM_Sum.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftHdM5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You could have N such loads, and as long as the *total* current doesn't exceed the capacity of the wiring and conductors involved, it would be OK. One hundred twenty 10 W LED lights (1200 W total) or a single 1.2 kW heater are examples of how the number of devices is not what's important.

Technically, your extension shouldn't have a "power output" rating at all. It neither consumes nor outputs power. It merely transfers energy. (Slight lie, it does consume a little due to inefficiencies, but we're ignoring that.) The power rating on it is more of a convenient shorthand for the end user. If you have a few devices in mind you should know what their power consumption is and avoid exceeding the rating of the extension. In other words, if you have *four* 1.2 kW heaters, you shouldn't use them all at the same time on the extension.

If you like videos, there's an [entertaining rant about extension outlets/splitters by Technology Connections](https://youtu.be/K_q-xnYRugQ) which ultimately focuses on the fact that it's up to the end user to know not to exceed such ratings, otherwise one is dependent on the hopefully-included safety mechanisms such as fuses and circuit breakers.

Answer (score -1):

**Q1**
To use ohm law in AC, we need more info then just the RMS value to calculate the power. This is where apparent and reactive power comes in. In most household application, you can neglect that and use the RMS value. If your load is mostly resistive (the case of most household appliance), you can approximate by Vrms=Z Irms or Prms=Vrms Irms.

**Q2**
Most likely yes. The rating on an appliance is often the maximum power they will consume. If you try to sink to much current, your system should be protected and fail (break pops or fuse blow).

**Q3**
Not sure I understand your last question but you can see an electrical system as a water loop. The source push water with a certain pressure. The flow of water is the current and the pressure is the voltage. If you have 4 water outlet in your house and an infinite supply of water (the city water for instance), you will have the same pressure at all outlets. The flow might be different depending on how much the valve is open.

Comment: "in AC, it is v[t]=Zi[t]", uh no?  Only if you consider Z a linear operator that can assume "values" like "L d/dt".  Otherwise things get a lot more complicated, and that's even with strictly linear components.

Comment: I forgot to mention that Z is a complex number. I corrected it.

Comment: If you want to do complex AC arithmetic, you cannot use v[t] and i[t]: there cannot be a time-dependency involved.  And the calculations only hold for a single frequency.  You are underselling the involved complexity.

Comment: Fair enough. I removed it since it's unclear that it is only true for a single frequency.